# How to Curve the hypotenuse of a triangle with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to curve the hypotenuse side of this triangle `div/background` with CSS, so the result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Not possible. You need to use SVG or canvas to draw that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

background can do it:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: radial-gradient(180% 180% at right -65% top -65%, transparent 99%, red )
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, matching the background you are in with a pseudo :after covering the part you need :

Althogh I like more @Temani Afif answer above.

```css
#curved-triangle::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#curved-triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <div id="curved-triangle"></div>
```