# How can I reproduce this curve in CSS?

Tags: css, svg

I want to create this shape using CSS:

[image: create this shape in css]

I used clip-path before but it only makes polygons but I'm trying to make it curvy

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you use `clip-path` enough, you can even make a circle

Comment: duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/q/66312497/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CSS only you can use `ellipse` within a `clip-path`.

```css
.shape {
  background: orange;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}

.shape:after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: ellipse(100px 120px at -10px -10px);  
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

The disadvantage of this is that `clip-path` only allows you to select which parts to keep, not which parts to remove. This means that the cut-out part will be white not transparent.

As you can see, we're not cutting the orange part, but adding the white circle on top of an orange background.

If you want a specific shape you might be better of with using an SVG as Andrew suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 69.2 100"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#f7931e;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M69.2,100H0C39.29,81.25,57.14,33,69.2,0Z"/></g></g></svg>
```

Creating svg curves is rather complicated, so it is often best to use a tool to assist. I created the above code used Adobe Ilustrator. Learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp

Comment: The question asks how to create the curve using CSS.

Comment: @Sean and yet it's tagged with the svg tag as well as CSS. If the OP wants a CSS solution, then this answer could be converted to a data URL and used as a clip-path.

Comment: @RobertLongson Tagging the question with SVG doesn't mean the OP wants an SVG solution. It just means it's related to SVG. Presumably the original graphic is SVG.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cut-out parts to be transparent then radial-gradient may be helpful.

e.g.

```css
div {
  background-image: radial-gradient(at -20vmin -60vmin, transparent 0%, transparent 80%, orange 80%, orange 100%);
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 60vmin;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: you can omit the `ellipse` keywords since it's default shape

Comment: Thanks yes, I'd forgotten and had circle to start. Will update snippet - always nice to minimize stuff.